# Function to return non-null value not working properly when saving data to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I get an array of objects from an API call and then I filter the values depending on two keys: `story_title` and `title`. If both values are null then the object is filtered. Then I loop through the filtered array of objects to save certain data to mongodb (using mongoose) from the filtered array. The problem is that I want to save the document with one `title` key, so I created a function to check if `story_title` or `title` is null and return the non-null value.

The function is not working properly because the function in `title`, inside the `for` loop, is returning some `null` values.

```
function pickTitle(title, story_title) {
    if (!story_title) {
        return story_title;
    } else {
        return title
    }
}

everyHour: async () => {
        try {
            data = await axios.get(url);
            let posts = data.data.hits;
            const filteredPosts = await posts.filter((elem) => {
                return (!elem.title || !elem.story_title)
            });

            for (let filtered of filteredPosts) {
                Post.updateOne({
                    _id: filtered.objectID,
                    author: filtered.author,
                    title: await pickTitle(filtered.title, filtered.story_title),
                    created_at: filtered.created_at,
                    },
                    {$setOnInsert: filtered}, 
                    {upsert: true}, 
                    function(err, numAffected) {
                        if (err) {
                            //console.log("err")
                        } else {
                            //console.log(numAffected)
                        }
                    })
                    .then(res => {
                        //console.log(res)
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        //console.log(err)
                    });
            }
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here.  I'll step through them in some comments in the code, as well as having the "solution" directly below the commented code.

- You are awaiting calls that are not asynchronous... don't do that.  Array.filter is not an asynchronous operation
- Your function `pickTitle` is being `await`ed, when it's not asynchronous
- Your resolving promises inside a loop, which is generally considered bad practice.  Add your promises to an array, and resolve everyone with `Promise.all()`
- Lastly, your "filter" logic filters on NULL `title` OR `story_title`.  That means only one needs to hold true.  It's possible that both could be NULL though.  Thus your `pickTitle` function returns a null value if both happen to be NULL.  If you want to always have *at least* one of them contain a value, you need to change the way your array.filter works.

---

```
const pickTitle = (title, story_title) => {
  if (!story_title) {
    return story_title;
  }
  return title;
};

async () => {
  try {
    data = await axios.get(url);
    const posts = data.data.hits;
    // const filteredPosts = await posts.filter(elem => (!elem.title || !elem.story_title));  <-- you are awaiting on a filter... don't do that
    const filteredPosts = posts.filter(elem => (!elem.title || !elem.story_title));
    const filteredPostAnotherWay = posts.filter(post => { // <-- This might be more of what you want...
      let allowed = false;
      if (!post.title) {
        allowed = true;
      }
      if (!post.story_title) {
        allowed = true;
      }

      return allowed;
    });
    const postUpdates = [];

    for (const filtered of filteredPosts) {
      // Post.updateOne({   <-- You are resolving promises inside a for loop.  While it may work, it's generally not advised to do this.  Resolve everything with promise.all instead....
      //   _id:        filtered.objectID,
      //   author:     filtered.author,
      //   title:      await pickTitle(filtered.title, filtered.story_title),
      //   created_at: filtered.created_at,
      //   story_url:  filtered.story_url
      // },
      // { $setOnInsert: filtered },
      // { upsert: true },
      // (err, numAffected) => {
      //   if (err) {
      //     // console.log("err")
      //   } else {
      //     // console.log(numAffected)
      //   }
      // })
      //   .then(res => {
      //     // console.log(res)
      //   })
      //   .catch(err => {
      //     // console.log(err)
      //   });

      postUpdates.push(
        Post.updateOne({
          _id:        filtered.objectID,
          author:     filtered.author,
          // title:      await pickTitle(filtered.title, filtered.story_title), // <-- You are awaiting a non asynchronous function... why?
          title:      pickTitle(filtered.title, filtered.story_title),
          created_at: filtered.created_at,
          story_url:  filtered.story_url
        },
        { $setOnInsert: filtered },
        { upsert: true },
        (err, numAffected) => {
          if (err) {
          // console.log("err")
          } else {
          // console.log(numAffected)
          }
        })
      );
    }

    return Promise.all(postUpdates);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It's not working though. First, I'm still saving `title` as null in some cases. Second, I'm getting this error at the end `(node:3240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: 5b913e0096e8216a560bcbe3_testing.posts index: _id_ dup key: { : "17904322" }
`
I think I didn't explain myself right. One of the things I need to do is to only save the objects from the API if the object is not already there.

Comment: The question about the async call in pickTitle was a mistake after trying deleting and rewriting everything, sorry for that

Comment: That's because you're always doing inserts based on your filter criteria.  Try reducing what you filter simply down to the object id: `Post.updateOne({ _id: filtered.objectID }, ...)`  You're attempting to filter on the exact fields you want to update to, thus the filter never matches, and it sees this as an insert and throws that dupe key.